# Creating an INNER JOIN from 2 tables IF condition is met

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause, exists

I have 2 tables, `Products` and `Orders`. If somebody creates an order, I want `Product_Name01` from `Orders` to be filled in by the Product_Name from `Products`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QZ0J.png)

The code below does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM Sandbox.dbo.orders o 
SELECT * FROM Sandbox.dbo.Products p 
INNER JOIN o -- is this the target table? 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT Product_Name01
    FROM o
    WHERE b.Product_ID01 = o.Product_ID )
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score -1):

I think the inner join already "checks" if both tables have matching records.
"The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables."- - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

So your query should probably just look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Sandbox.dbo.orders o 
INNER JOIN Sandbox.dbo.Products p
    ON b.Product_ID01 = o.Product_ID;
```

Comment: Many thanks! So it does seem I did misunderstood how the INNER JOIN works with the check. Thought I had to do it myself. 

I don't get an error with your query, however it still leaves the "Name01" blank.
I've changed the query to below, as it is supposed to fill in the Product_Name01. 
Unless I'm misunderstanding that part as well? 

'''
SELECT * FROM Sandbox.dbo.orders o 
INNER JOIN Sandbox.dbo.Products p
    ON o.Product_Name01 = o.Product_Name;
'''